# how do I to put attributes **response.sendRedirect()**

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, redirect, forwarding

How do I to put attributes on a redirection response like putting attributes on a request of a forwarding please ? In the beginning, I thought that it was possible to set them as respone.setAttribute(..), but this method doesn't exist. any help please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: in a redirection I believe it will only send the header and even if it sends the rest the browser would likely ignore it and do the redirect. What specifically are you attempting? Code would be helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to send an Object to the redirected link

Comment: Is the answer below insufficient? The problem with what you are trying to do is that a redirect by definition is a GET request, not a POST, so the only way to add data is to encode and concatenate it to the URI, otherwise the data won't get to the resource you are redirecting to.

Answer (score 0):

A redirect consists in telling the browser: "please go there (there being a URL) by sending a new GET request". So, if you want to pass parameters to the component that will receive this second request, you'll have to pass these parameters in the URL:

```
response.sendRedirect("/foo/bar/baz?param1=value1&param2=value2");
```

Comment: I need to set an Object as an Attribute

Comment: Then store it in the database or in a session attribute before redirecting. Only String parameters can be passed.